How to get forwarded calls log via ADB
I am trying to obtain some info about the forwarding call facility in Android using the ADB tool from my computer (device attached to USB port and USB debugging enabled). I'm looking for evidence of changes in settings about enabling and disabling call forwarding and the phone numbers used for that.
I've tried some commands like

adb shell content query --uri content://call_log/calls and
adb shell settings get global last_call_forward_action.

But the information that I need is not present. The logcat shows something from the past, but its time range is limited to a few days and I want to know what happened several weeks ago.
Is that possible? Should I use another different tool?

Note that adb is only a short-term log system where old messages are overwritten if the buffer limit is reached. Depending on your device and the logcat volume the buffer may hold messages of the last hours up to may be one or two days See Is it possible to somehow understand from the logs what happened to the phone a month ago? Are there such logs?
